# How do I save nii files into one nii file using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nifti

I have 360 3D-nifti files, I want to read all these files and save into one nifti file using [Nifti Analyze tool](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image) that should yield a 4D file of large size. So far I have written following lines

```
clear all;
clc; 

fileFolder=fullfile(pwd, '\functional');
files=dir(fullfile(fileFolder, '*.nii'));
fileNames={files.name};

     for i=1:length(fileNames)

          fname=fullfile(fileFolder,fileNames{i});
          z(i)=load_nii(fname);
          y=z(i).img;
          temp(:,:,:,i) = make_nii(y);
          save_nii(temp(:,:,:,i), 'myfile.nii')

fprintf('Iter:  %d\n', i)
end
```

This code facilitates with a variable temp that is 4D struct and contains all the images. However, myfile.nii is just one single file its not all the images because its size is just 6mb it should be atleast one 1gb.
Can someone please have a look and let me know where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that you have it written, your loop is *overwriting* `myfile.nii` since you're calling `save_nii` every time through the loop with only the latest data. You'll want to instead call `save_nii` only once outside of the loop and save the entire `temp` variable at once.

```
for k = 1:numel(fileNames)
    fname = fullfile(fileFolder, fileNames{k});
    z(k) = load_nii(fname);
    y(:,:,:,k) = z(k).img;
end

% Create the ND Nifti file
output = make_nii(y);

% Save it to a file
save_nii(output, 'myfile.nii')
```

Comment: I tried before and I get an error relating to struct at the line save_nii. The error is 'Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by more reference blocks is an error'.  I think this is because there are two elements in temp one .img and other is .hdr.
Can you please comment on this ? Any workarounds?

Comment: It gets solved by calling make_nii  and save_nii outside the loop e.g.  
                 Loop:
                 y(:,:,:,i)=x(i).img
                 end
                 temp=make_nii(y)
                 save_nii(temp,'myfile.nii')

 Thanks for the clue.

Comment: @Vendetta Sorry, just saw your comment from yesterday. Yes, you're right, you'll have to create the file using `make_nii` outside of the loop as well. I've updated the answer accordingly